# Ionic v3 - How to change button's "color"-attribute when clicked

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

Ionic v3

I'm viewing a list of notifications in my demo app.

List code (notifications.html)

```
  <ion-list>
    <button ion-item *ngFor="let post of posts" color="{{post.color}}" id="btn_{{post.item}}" (click)="readNotification(post.item)" >
      <ion-icon name="{{post.icon}}" item-start></ion-icon>
      <h2>{{post.title}}</h2>
      <p>{{post.content}}</p>
    </button>
  </ion-list>
```

**I want to change the colour of the clicked item when clicked from "primary" to "light" if it is "primary" when clicked.**

Now the click function calls "readNotification"-function and opens a new view to show the full message.

Default color is specified in the ajax data. If the message is not readed, it will be displayed with "primary" color and if it is already read it will be displayed with "light" color.

#### UPDATE

Notifications.ts

```
export class NotificationsPage {
  posts: any;

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public http: Http,
    private localNotifications:
    LocalNotifications
  ) {
    this.http.get('xxx?oper=getNotificationsJSON')
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.posts = data.results;
    },
    err => {
      console.log("oops!");
    });
  }

  readNotification(item: string) {
    this.navCtrl.push(ReadNotificationPage, {
      id: item
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? And share important parts of your component please

Comment: I just don't know how to add this "change color" functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed click operation to *readNotification(post)* and now it is possible to change and edit the post item in *readNotification*-function.

Thanks for your help!

Notifications.html

```
  <ion-list>
    <button ion-item *ngFor="let post of posts" color="{{post.color}}" (click)="readNotification(post)" >
      <ion-icon name="{{post.icon}}" item-start></ion-icon>
      <h2>{{post.title}}</h2>
      <p>{{post.content}}</p>
    </button>
  </ion-list>
```

Notifications.ts

```
export class NotificationsPage {
  posts: any;

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public http: Http,
    private localNotifications:
    LocalNotifications
  ) {
    this.http.get('xxx?oper=getNotificationsJSON')
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.posts = data.results;
    },
    err => {
      console.log("oops!");
    });
  }

  readNotification(post) {
      post.color = 'light';
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you can get rid of `readNotification` with `(click)="post.color = 'light'"`.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have all the pieces already.

You have a property that it used in your template to specify a color.

#### HTML

```
<button ion-button (click)="readNotification()" color="{{post.color}}">change color</button>
```

Then in your function all you have to do it modify the proprety

#### Page class

```
public post: any = {color: 'primary'};

public readNotification() {
    this.post.color = 'light';
}
```

Comment: Is there any other way to do this? The default color is specified with {{post.color}} and is readed when the list is initialized. The list is dynamic and generated by JSON data when loaded.

Comment: Then when your data is loaded, look at the 'read' property and update the button color. Post your ajax code if you need more help.

Comment: "Notifications.ts"

`export class NotificationsPage {
  posts: any;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public http: Http, private localNotifications: LocalNotifications) {
    this.http.get('https://xxx?oper=getNotificationsJSON').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
        this.posts = data.results ;
    },
    err => { console.log("oops!"); }
    );  
  }
  readNotification(item: string) {
    this.navCtrl.push(ReadNotificationPage, { id: item });
  }
}`

This works fine, but I do not want to reload JSON data when clicked - just want to change color of btn.

Comment: If you want the color to change on click then the change has to happen in the `readNotification` method.

Comment: Thank you for your patience! now I figured out how to do this and it was so simple! A moment and i'll post the solution...

Answer (score 0):

All that you need is just to check in your function, does `post.color` has `"primary"` value, and if it is, then change the value to `"light"`:

```
readNotification(): void {
  // do stuff with "post.item" and everything you want

  if (post.color === "primary") {
    post.color = "light"; // will change the color to "light" only if the current color is "primary"
  }
}
```